# Headless chrome nodejs async loop for scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-headless

I'm having a play around with nodejs and the way we can now have a headless chrome browser and interact with it which is pretty awesome!

I have some code and I have it working for scraping 1 website without any issues. However when I want to scrape multiple my loop just seems to mess it up and i'm pretty sure it's all to do with async/await.

My loop is near the bottom of this code - does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks heaps!

```
const HeadlessChrome = require('simple-headless-chrome')

const browser = new HeadlessChrome({
  headless: true, // If you turn this off, you can actually see the browser navigate with your instructions,
})

async function navigateWebsite(urlToGoTo) {
  try {
    await browser.init()

    const mainTab = await browser.newTab({
      privateTab: false
    })

    await mainTab.inject('jquery')

    let cookieName = 'li_at'
    let cookieValue = 'cyzzzzzzzzz'
    let cookieDomain = '.www.linkedin.com'

    await mainTab.setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, {
      domain: cookieDomain
    })

    // Navigate to a URL
    await mainTab.goTo(urlToGoTo)
    await mainTab.wait(2000);

    // Get a HTML tag value based on class id
    let businessName = await mainTab.evaluate(function (selector) {
      const selectorHtml = document.querySelector(selector)
      return selectorHtml.innerHTML
    }, '.org-top-card-module__name');

    let industry = await mainTab.evaluate(function (selector) {
      const selectorHtml = document.querySelector(selector)
      return selectorHtml.innerHTML
    }, '.company-industries');

    let followers = await mainTab.evaluate(function (selector) {
      const selectorHtml = document.querySelector(selector)
      return selectorHtml.innerHTML
    }, '.org-top-card-module__followers-count');

    let details = {
      businessName: cleanData(businessName),
      industry: cleanData(industry),
      followers: cleanData(followers)
    }

    console.log(details)


    // Resize the viewport to full screen size (One use is to take full size screen shots)
    await mainTab.resizeFullScreen()

    // Take a screenshot
    await mainTab.saveScreenshot()

    // Close the browser
    await browser.close()

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ERROR!', err)
  }
}

let websites = []

websites.push('https://www.linkedin.com/company/qrious-limited/')
websites.push('https://www.linkedin.com/company/wentworth-consulting-nz-/')
websites.push('https://www.linkedin.com/company/capita/')

websites.forEach(function (i) {
   navigateWebsite(i)
})


function cleanData(a) {
  return a.result.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").trim()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`navigateWebsite()` is asynchronous but it's not awaited. You could use `Promise.all()` mapping your list of websites to your nav function or make sure to `await` each result.

```
Promise.all(websites.map(w => navigateWebsite(w)));
// or
for (let w of websites) {
  await navigateWebsite(w);
}
```